# How to configure Visual SVN Server with Different Host Header

Tags: svn, dns, visualsvn-server, visualsvn

I want my Repositories to be accessed to something like this:

```
http://projectone.myserver.com
http://projecttwo.myserver.com
```

They should have the same port number (port 80)

On IIS this is possible using the host names. How can I do this on Visual SVN Server?